# Skyrim keeps freezing, what do I do?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, ps3

Skyrim keeps freezing on my PS3. I can't set it back to factory settings because it was downloaded.

I've tried uninstalling and re-installing it. It keeps freezing as soon as Alduin (the dragon) comes and attacks Helgen. Is there a way to get it up and running again without having to wipe all of my data?

Comment: sounds like a corrupted texture file of some kind, is there any way you can check file integrity on the PS3?

Comment: @z' Definitely not a file issue, as that would cause the game to freeze right after or even during the loading screen. As far as I know, Skyrim doesn't load while playing like some modern games do.

Comment: @Kevin Skyrim absolutely loads textures and sounds while playing.  its 16 GBs in size on the hard drive.  The PS3 doesn't have that much RAM to hold the entire game in memory

Comment: @z' Size on disk has nothing to do with what is loaded in RAM. What I meant with "loading while playing" is what, for example, World of warcraft does. It loads textures asynchronously while playing, so there is hardly any loading noticeable. Skyrim does the loading in loading screens, interrupting gameplay to load new data.

Comment: @Kevin ah, I see I misunderstood your 'while playing' part.

Answer (score 7):

I have a couple of suggestions that might come in handy that I got from a quick search:

1. Clean up your PS3's drive and ensure that you have at least 2G of free space.
2. Go into the saved data utility and delete all "corrupted file" items that you find there. These files will have the word "corrupted" in the name.
3. Launch the game and open the game options and turn off all four auto-save options. You will then have to play old-school creating your own manual saves but it helps a lot.
4. Inside of the game "Wait" for 30 game days (I did 31 just to be sure). Create a save and restart the game. This will have the game do its own cleanup of objects in the world such as arrows that you fired and missed that are still lying around, most of the bodies (some will stay), etc and thus have less objects to worry about.

The last item, number 4, had the biggest impact on my play.

Bethesda says that the problem is due to the split memory model that PS3 uses for its hardware. The issue was visible in their previous titles but it gets more pronounced the more stuff you have in the world (hence the longer you play) and there is a lot more stuff in Skyrim than the previous titles.

If that doesn't work you should consider the following?

1. Is your PS3 overheating? If so you should make sure you keep it in a nice hard surfaced area (not on carpet which really attracts dust), give it some nice room to breath (you wouldn't like it if you were placed with a bunch of other equipment in a small area). Just to be safe about once a week check on your vents see if their not blocked with dust If they are grab a cleaning cloth and a low powered vacuum and clean your system.

Sources:

http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/615804-the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/66161794
https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20090723172055AAFdKGk

*PS. I couldn't post all sources I need at least 10 rep. Sorry*

Answer (score -2):

Auto saves should be turned off (all of them) this helps reduce the fast travel loading screen and less junk files to the game to recognize and the system could be over heating. This could also be the space is too low on the system I restarted my system (ps3) and put a fan facing it to stop it from overheating. This should help the game if it is freezing on you :) hope it helped